# graphql-http Missing query

Tags: express, graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

Followed steps by steps just trying to integrate graphql from provided documentation of expressjs,
https://github.com/graphql/graphql-http#with-express

```
import express from 'express'; // yarn add express
import { createHandler } from 'graphql-http/lib/use/express';
import { GraphQLSchema, GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString } from 'graphql';


const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
        hello: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve: () => 'world',
        },
    },
    }),
});


const app = express();

app.use(
    '/graphql',
    createHandler({ schema:schema,graphiql:true}),
  )
```

I am not getting UI interface to run query just getting following response

{"errors":[{"message":"Missing query"}]}
400 Bed Request

Get UI to play query strig or something to implement new query strings / APIs

Answer (score 2):

`graphql-http` package does not provide an out-of-a-box GraphqQL Playground UI. There is no `graphiql` option for the `createHandler` function.

[Only GraphQL over HTTP](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-http#only-graphql-over-http) and this [issue](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-http/discussions/38#discussioncomment-4698804)

> This is the official GraphQL over HTTP spec reference implementation and as such follows the specification strictly without any additional features (like playgrounds or GUIs, file uploads, @stream/@defer directives and subscriptions).

You can use [graphql-playground-middleware-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-playground-middleware-express) to expose an endpoint for the GraphQL Playground.

E.g.

```
const express = require('express');
const { createHandler } = require('graphql-http/lib/use/express');
const expressPlayground =
  require('graphql-playground-middleware-express').default;
const { GraphQLSchema, GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString } = require('graphql');

/**
 * Construct a GraphQL schema and define the necessary resolvers.
 *
 * type Query {
 *   hello: String
 * }
 */
const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
      hello: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve: () => 'world',
      },
    },
  }),
});

const app = express();

app.all('/graphql', createHandler({ schema }));
app.get('/playground', expressPlayground({ endpoint: '/graphql' }));

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Server is running on PORT 4000...'));
```

Access `https://so76735343-0n0m--4000--c53ab388.local-corp.webcontainer.io/playground` endpoint, you will see GraphQL playground UI.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-76735343?file=index.js)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with GraphQL UI, I recommend using Apollo Server's standalone web server. For [more](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started) informations.

Standalone web server is easy to set up. Generate `typeDefs` and `resolvers` and then build the server.

You can use the code below.

```
import { ApolloServer } from "@apollo/server";
import { startStandaloneServer } from "@apollo/server/standalone";

// types and resolvers
import { typeDefs, resolvers } from "./schema.js";

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server, {
  listen: { port: 4000 },
});

console.log(`  Server ready at: ${url}`);
```

But if you want to work with web integrations, you can use [Apollo Server integrations.](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/integration-index/) For example, you can use [`expressMiddleware`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/express-middleware) for Express framework. But you won't see an UI, you have to create request with applications like postman or insomnia etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete working example from [graphql.org](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/running-an-express-graphql-server/). The server will be started on port 4000 and you will see the Graphiql ui by visiting http://127.0.0.1:4000/ no need to attach anything more to this root path.

```js
var express = require("express")
var { createHandler } = require("graphql-http/lib/use/express")
var { buildSchema } = require("graphql")
var { ruruHTML } = require("ruru/server")

// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
var schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`)

// The root provides a resolver function for each API endpoint
var root = {
  hello: () => {
    return "Hello world!"
  },
}

var app = express()

// Create and use the GraphQL handler.
app.all(
  "/graphql",
  createHandler({
    schema: schema,
    rootValue: root,
  })
)

// Serve the GraphiQL IDE.
app.get("/", (_req, res) => {
  res.type("html")
  res.end(ruruHTML({ endpoint: "/graphql" }))
})

// Start the server at port
app.listen(4000)
console.log("Running a GraphQL API server at http://localhost:4000/graphql")
```